# QGIS - How to put Grid coordinates on two separate lines

Tags: qgis, coordinates, grids-graticules

Im making a map & I want to put the grid coordinates on two lines like this:
[image]

I cant seem to find any option to do such a thing in the QGIS layout composer.

Anyone have a suggestion on how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are specifically asking about the numbering, you can do this using 2 grids, under **Grids** in the **Item Properties**.

For the first grid, under the **Draw Co-ordinates** section, set **Format** = *Custom*, using the following formula:

`lpad(@grid_number / 1000 - floor(@grid_number / 1000000) * 1000, 3,'0')`

This will get you the first 3 digits of the grid, padded with '0' if necessary.

Also under **Draw Co-ordinates**, set all sides to *Inside Frame*, and *Above Tick*.

[image]

For the second grid, set **Format** = *Custom*, with the following formula:

`lpad(@grid_number % 1000, 3,'0')`

Set *Inside Frame*, and *Below Tick* for all sides.

Depending on what lines you have/want, you may need to set line style Opacity = 0%, as you already have the grid lines.

[image]

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but thank you so much for explaining all this. It worked perfectly & I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the item properties of your map. Scroll down to Rasters and press the green plus to add one to your map.

[image]

Then, go to adjust raster. Under 'Frame' you can choose your desired type of showing the coordinates. Scroll further down to 'Draw coordinates'. Tick the box to show the coordinates on your map.

[image]
[image]

You may have to adjust the interval of your raster under 'appearance' to match your desired raster.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response! It's very helpful. But im struggling to find the 'Raster' heading in QGIS composer?

Im using QGIS 3.30. Is this feature somewhere else on my version?

Comment: It is called "Grid" in english QGIS

Comment: Thank you! 

But is there a trick to get the coordinates on two lines around the tick, like in this example https://imgur.com/a/i8XxFxy: