QGIS: Labeling text out side of map?
I have some grid lines which have attributes (map 1). Those attribute need to show outside of map area in layout section where arrow is (map 2). How to do that?



Is there a reason you aren't just using the Add Grid functionality inside the Layout Composer? It allows you to do just that (add labels outside the frame)

How is it possible using own data and not calculated? any examples?

Depends on your exact requirements, but this question/answer has some instructions on the grid. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/459814/qgis-how-to-put-grid-coordinates-on-two-separate-lines/459886#459886

I understand, I try to label lines which are not able to create by Add Grid -function

Maybe you can explain in the question why you think your lines can't be created by the Add Grid

Sure, if I using like the road lines with names which road name I want to show also outside of map
